# Auto Increment ID in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to add a record to a table and have the primary key be auto generated. I have the `StudentID` column as primary key, `int, not null` in SQL Server. I keep getting this error:

> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Student ID', table 'SchoolManagement.dbo.Student'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Model (Student.CS):

```
namespace SchoolChallenge.Models
{
    public partial class Student
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string StudentNumber { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
        public string HasScholarship { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller (`StudentsController`):

```
// POST: Students/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("StudentId,StudentNumber,FirstName,LastName,HasScholarship")] Student student)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(student);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(student);
}
```

SchoolManagementContext.cs:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.StudentId)
        .HasColumnName("Student ID")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    entity.Property(e => e.FirstName)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("First Name")
        .HasMaxLength(50);

    entity.Property(e => e.HasScholarship)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("Has Scholarship")
        .HasColumnType("nchar(10)");

    entity.Property(e => e.LastName)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("Last Name")
        .HasMaxLength(50);

    entity.Property(e => e.StudentNumber).HasColumnName("Student Number");
});
```

Comment: Whether you used `database first` or `code first`?

Comment: Database first. Do i need to set the Identity in MSSQL?

Comment: Yes. You should do it.

Comment: If you're using Code First, try `modelBuilder.Entity<Student>(...).HasKey(p => p.StudentId).Property(p => p.StudentId).StoreGeneratedPattern = StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity;`. If DB First is used, try setting `StudentId` column as `IDENTITY (1, 1)` & don't forget to set `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `Identity` in EDMX file.

Comment: in your Create method have you tried removing the StudentId property from your Bind attribute?

Comment: Yes I have but I use that for a view as well so I get a totally different error.

Comment: @Freiza1991 What error found afterwards? I suggest you using a `Student` viewmodel class besides `Student` data model generated class rather that `BindAttribute`. To use identity autogenerated column, skip the column name binding when doing submit with `HttpPostAttribute`.

Comment: I ended up changing the Identity in MSSQL for my primary keys and now it autoincrements correctly.

Answer (score 6):

If your code does not provide student ID then you must make it an identity field in your table.

Make sure the student ID field has this in the table design.

```
IDENTITY (1,1)
```

This will automatically generate the student ID for you in the database on row insert and increment the ID by 1 for every new row.

I dont believe you can make a column identity after its made iirc. So either drop the table and recreate or drop the incorrect column and replace with the correct one.

So to drop a column and add a new one:

```
Alter TABLE dbo.t_name drop column studentID
```

Then:

```
Alter TABLE dbo.t_name add studentID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

Comment: it would be better if you can provide alter script for OP too, because i think table already creeated

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `Identity` of my primary key from `No` to `Yes` in SQL Server, and now it auto increments and no error is displayed.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Visual Studio, you can edit the primary ID, by opening the table definition.  Open the Server Explorer, right click on the table, and select "open table definition".  Under the "Design" tab at the bottom, either add or edit the following:

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TableName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
```

Comment: This is not the problem. And the PK already exists.